# Is there a rule to justify the following logical statement?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-verification

I have to derive the following expression and reach the second one:

> $$\begin{gather}
> ( ( \forall x , Q \Rightarrow \neg P (x) ) \wedge ( \forall x, \neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P(x) ) ) \\
> \iff \\
> ( \neg \exists x, P(x) )
> \end{gather}$$

After working the expression with some of the manipulation rules, these are some of my final steps:

> $$\begin{align}
> &\forall x, ( \neg P(x) \vee \neg Q ) \wedge ( \neg P(x) \vee Q ) \tag{1} &\text{(#commutativity)} \\
> &\forall x, ( \neg P(x) ) \wedge ( \neg Q \vee Q ) &\text{(#identity)} \tag{2} \\ 
> &\forall x, \neg P(x) &\text{(#negation)} \\
> &\neg ( \exists x, P(x) )
> \end{align}$$

That would work, however, is there any rule to justify what I did to get to the second line from the first one? Or a process I could apply?

Comment: You should replace picture with latex formula.

Comment: It's a derived rule that conjunction distributes over alternation, and similarly for alternation over conjunction. I find it useful enough that I think they should be named rules of inference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Natural Deduction (and assuming that my "translation" of your formulae is correct) :

(1) --- $\forall x(Q \rightarrow \neg P(x) ) \wedge \forall x(\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P(x) )$

with $\wedge$-elim :

$\forall x(Q \rightarrow \neg P(x) )$

with $\forall$-elim:

$Q \rightarrow \neg P(x)$

(a) assume $Q$ and by $\rightarrow$-elim :

$\neg P(x)$

In the same way, from (1) :

$\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P(x)$

(b) assume $\neg Q$ and by $\rightarrow$-elim :

$\neg P(x)$

Using now $\lor$-intro (or *proof by cases*) with the axiom $Q \lor \neg Q$ we have :

(2) --- $\neg P$, discharging assumption (a) and (b).

Now apply $\forall$-intro to (2) :

$\forall x \neg P(x)$

that is :

(3) --- $\neg \exists x P(x)$.